# How to build 'many-to-many' rrelationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to have a 'many-to-many' relationship between `users` and `products`. For this, I prepared another table `product_user` but it is not working well. I can't use it in secondary `relationship`.

Error:

> NameError: name 'product_users' is not defined

This is code:

```py
## Product model
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary=product_users, backref="users", lazy="dynamic")   

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product %r>' % self.uid

## User model
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=product_users, backref="products", lazy="dynamic")   

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.uid

## Product User model
class ProductUser(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product_users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('products.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    product = db.relationship("Product", backref='products', foreign_keys=[product_id])
    user = db.relationship("User", backref='users', foreign_keys=[user_id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ProductUser %r>'
```

Comment: You should check your spelling. You have ProdductUser, ProductUser, Produuct and Product...

Comment: I had updated the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have typo `table name`.

from:

```py
users = db.relationship("User", secondary=product_users, backref="users", lazy="dynamic")   
products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=product_users, backref="products", lazy="dynamic")
```

to:

```py
users = db.relationship("User", secondary='product_users', backref="users", lazy="dynamic")   
products = db.relationship("Product", secondary='product_users', backref="products", lazy="dynamic")
```